# How to remove a remote source from gem remote sources

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have added gemcutter.org to my Rubygems sources, and now I do not know how to remove it.

```
$ gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://gemcutter.org
http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

Comment: Why would you want to remove it though? http://www.rubyinside.com/gemcutter-is-the-new-official-default-rubygem-host-2659.html

Comment: I had to check if a gem is deleted from gems.rubyforge.org gem index, and the only way I could be sure is to remove all other sources.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
$ gem sources -r http://gemcutter.org
http://gemcutter.org removed from sources

$ gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

Answer (score 3):

In general you can find the syntax with

```
gem help *command*
```

So this shows the options you needed:

```
gem help sources
```

Answer (score 1):

But what if the problem is that the default source causes gem install to hang on non-connected systems? (You think it's impossible?!?)  If you run the command provided by the most popular answer, and this happens:

```
# gem sources -r https://rubygems.org
source https://rubygems.org not present in cache
```

Then to deal with this situation, you must modify source *cringe*:

```
sed -i '/[[:space:]]def self\.default_sources/a return []'   \
  $RUBYGEMS_DIR/rubygems/defaults.rb
```

This adds a line of code, namely `return []` to return an empty array, after the method that returns "default sources". Run `gem environment` and you will see no nasty remote sources. Now you can go back and undo the sed command, or manually add the rubygems repo or whatever.

EDIT: Clarify, generalize.

Comment: why would this ever be necessary? why not just remove the default sources?

Comment: The problem is that the "default source" is hard-coded and will cause everything to hang on non-connected systems.

Comment: @Otheus not true. I just successfully ran `gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/` on a machine where I was simulating a situation with no network egress. It stopped `gem install` from hanging.

Comment: @sixty4bit check the source code if your installation/distribution has this default line. Mine has: `def self.default_sources; %w[https://rubygems.org/]; end`  It's hardcoded.

Comment: @sixty4bit See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109279/determine-location-of-ruby-gems and from there, my answer above.

Comment: @Otheus I see. that method is just being used to set an instance variable in `rubygems.org`: `@sources ||= Gem::SourceList.from(default_sources)`. doesn't mean that the value of that instance variable can't be changed. if you look in `rubygems/commands/sources_command.rb` it has the logic for removing a source from the list of currently-loaded services. at any rate, that's just my quick superficial reading of the source code. all I know is when I do the command I referenced above, it says that the source has been removed and I no longer get any hanging

Comment: @sixty4bit The code you show (same as in mine) means: if the instance variable `@sources` is empty, populate it via the `default_sources` method. The `@sources` variable is populated via `sources=` method via `config_file.rb:initialize` which gets its values from various config files. The `sources_command.rb` file operates on the sources _from a config file_. It has no effect on the code, nor the defaults. The logic is bad, the code is bad. The fix is to remove the defaults.

Comment: I experienced this too and was able to remove the default with some combination of `gem sources -c` and `gem sources -u` then `gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/` was successful and finally `gem sources` returned empty list. Was swearing here, pretty nuts! I hope this gets fixed!