# Determine Location Of Ruby Gems

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

How do I determine the location of my ruby gems?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107141/ruby-on-rails-where-to-gems-actually-go

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy Question : Where do gems install to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408868/easy-question-where-do-gems-install-to)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

you can try

```
gem which rails
```

to fetch location for particular gem, or

```
echo $GEM_HOME
```

to fetch home dir of your gems

Comment: from within a rails program, use `ENV['GEM_HOME']`

Comment: `ENV['GEM_HOME']` return `nil` in `irb`

Comment: If the gem you are looking for can't be found, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601984/why-doesnt-the-command-gem-list-include-gems-installed-with-bundlers-git-op

Comment: So for example with `rbenv`, my gems are stored in `~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems`.

Answer (score 60):

```
gem environment
```

...should give you all the info you need.

Comment: this is better for who doesn't have rails

Answer (score 16):

With budler you can do:

```
bundle info <gem>
```

Result:

```
  * pg (1.4.5)
        Summary: Pg is the Ruby interface to the PostgreSQL RDBMS
        Homepage: https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg
        Path: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.3/gems/pg-1.4.5
```

Reference: https://bundler.io/v2.4/man/bundle-info.1.html

Comment: Deprecated. use `bundle info`  instead of `bundle show`

Comment: This can also find gems installed from version control (e.g.: git)

Answer (score 0):

The trivial solution would be:

```rb
gem environment
```

However, it shows a large output with many informations that we do not want to see, such as `RUBYGEMS VERSION`, `RUBY VERSION`, `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`, `USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`, `RUBY EXECUTABLE`, `GIT EXECUTABLE`, `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY`, `SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY`, `SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY`, `RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS`, `GEM CONFIGURATION`, `REMOTE SOURCES` and `SHELL PATH`.

**We just want the `GEM PATH`!**

I have a solution for this with `grep` + `awk`.

```rb
gem environment | grep -A 1 "GEM PATHS:" | awk 'NR==2 { sub(/^[[:space:]]+- /, ""); print }'
```

#### Explanation

1. `gem environment`: This command is used to display information about the RubyGems environment, including details about gem installations, paths, and configurations.
2. `grep -A 1 "GEM PATHS:"`: This part of the command is used to search for the line containing "GEM PATHS:" in the output of `gem environment` and include the line that follows it (`-A 1`) in the output. In other words, it extracts the line with "GEM PATHS:" and the line immediately below it.
3. `awk 'NR==2 { sub(/^[[:space:]]+- /, ""); print }'`:

   - `awk`: This is a powerful text processing tool that allows you to manipulate and process text files line by line.
   - `'NR==2'`: This is an AWK condition that specifies that the following actions should be performed only for the second line of input (the line below "GEM PATHS:").
   - `{ sub(/^[[:space:]]+- /, ""); print }`:

     - `sub(/^[[:space:]]+- /, "")`: This AWK function (`sub`) is used to substitute (replace) a pattern with another pattern. In this case, it's used to remove the leading spaces and hyphen (`^[[:space:]]+-` ) from the line.
     - `print`: This command is used to print the modified line to the standard output.

So, in summary, the command extracts the line below "GEM PATHS:" from the `gem environment` output, removes the leading spaces and hyphen from that line, and then prints the resulting file path.