# Why doesn't the command `gem list` include gems installed with bundler's :git option?

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundler

In our rails 3.2 `Gemfile`, there are some gems installed with option `:git` pointing to repo on `github`, such as:

```
gem 'ruote', :git => 'http://github.com/jmettraux/ruote.git'
```

After `bundle install`, we type `gem list` to list all the gems installed. However `gem list` does not list `ruote` as a gem installed. As a matter of fact, there is no `ruote` listed at all. We notice the same thing also happens to all rails `engines` which are installed with option `:git` pointing to repo on github. Why gem list does not list all gems installed? How can we assure that ruote is correctly installed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the [Bundler Documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.5/git.html), gems from git sources will not show up in `gem list` because the `gem` command cannot process them, so Bundler has to do all of the work by itself.  Bundler stores these gems in its own location instead. (Note that this location has nothing to do with the current project.  It is in `~/.bundler/...` by default.)

You can see that it is installed if `bundle install` completes with no errors.  You can also use `bundle show` to see the list of gems that Bundler has set up for you.

Comment: But how can you use those gems? I mean, a simple 'require' can't find them.

Comment: @refaelos Run your app using `bundle exec` and then a simple `require` is all you need.

Comment: Thanks @Moshe Katz! I noticed that also requiring bundle/setup inside the file works.

Comment: @refaelos yes, that is also a way to do it. I use the `bundle exec` way because it allows me to test with system gems instead of the bundled ones if I want to.

Answer (score 1):

`gem list` is not the right way to show gems installed for the app, as it will show system wide gems.

To check what gems are for this app and their versions, check `Gemfile.lock`. You'll have the most precise info there.

Answer (score 0):

`gem list` is showing you all the gems installed on your machine.

When you have a gem with a different location than Ruby's gems, Bundler will store these locally for the project rather than system wide.

Comment: `bundler` only stores the gems locally for the project if you use `--deployment`.